# Multiples group aggregate in mongodb

Tags: node.js, mongodb, mongoose, mongodb-query

Lets say i have a collection of books like this :

```
{author:"john",  category:"action", title:"foobar200"},  
{author:"peter", category:"scifi" , title:"42test"},  
{author:"peter", category:"novel",  title:"whatever_t"},  
{author:"jane",  category:"novel",  title:"the return"},  
{author:"john",  category:"action", title:"extreme test"},  
{author:"peter", category:"scifi",  title:"such title"},  
{author:"jane",  category:"action", title:"super book "}
```

I want to do a query similar to :
`SELECT author,category, count(*) FROM books GROUP BY category, author`
==> result :

```
john -> action -> 2  
john -> novel  -> 0  
john -> scifi  -> 0  
jane -> action -> 1
etc...
```

the closest i've been to the solution is this :

```
 db.books.aggregate(
       { 
         $match: {category:"action"} 
        }, 
       {
         $group: { _id: '$author', result: { $sum: 1 } } 
      }
);
```

==> result

```
{ "_id" : "jane",  "result" : 1 }
{ "_id" : "john",  "result" : 2 }
{ "_id" : "peter", "result" : 0 }
```

But i can't understand how to perform the second "group by" with categories.
 What is the best way to do this ?

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can include multiple fields in the `_id` used by `$group` to provide multi-field grouping:

```
db.books.aggregate([
    {$group: {
        _id: {category: '$category', author: '$author'}, 
        result: {$sum: 1}
    }}
])
```

Result:

```
{
    "_id" : {
        "category" : "action",
        "author" : "jane"
    },
    "result" : 1
}, 
{
    "_id" : {
        "category" : "novel",
        "author" : "jane"
    },
    "result" : 1
}, 
{
    "_id" : {
        "category" : "novel",
        "author" : "peter"
    },
    "result" : 1
}, 
{
    "_id" : {
        "category" : "scifi",
        "author" : "peter"
    },
    "result" : 2
}, 
{
    "_id" : {
        "category" : "action",
        "author" : "john"
    },
    "result" : 2
}
```

Comment: You can use $project to further shape the results like OP wanted:
> `db.books.aggregate([     {$group: {         _id: {category: '$category', author: '$author'},          result: {$sum:
 1}  }}, {$project: {_id: "$_id.author", result :  "$result" }} ])`

Comment: Do you know how can i project like : { autor : 'john', list: {action:2, scifi:3, novel:0 }} ?

Comment: @AbelChalier Best to post that as a new question.